# Add 100px to current marginleft onclick

Tags: javascript

I want to add 100px margin-left on each time a button is clicked. But I don't really know how to. This is what i came up with:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#test-button').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var marginleft = document.querySelector('.usp-item').style.marginLeft;
 marginleft += 100px;
}))
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: You are currently pulling out the value of the margin, saving it in a variable, and then updating that variable. You need to set the margin to equal that updated variable. (Also, `+= 100px` will not add up the way you expect, I would keep it as numbers in the variable and then add "px" once your sum is complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `marginLeft + 'px'` to `element.style.marginLeft`.

```js
document.querySelector('#test-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const item = document.querySelector('.usp-item');
  const marginLeft = parseInt(item.style.marginLeft.replace('px', '')) || 0;
  item.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + 100 + 'px';
});
```

```css
.usp-item {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="usp-item"></div>

<button id="test-button">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#test-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let marginLeft = parseInt(document.querySelector('.usp-item').style.marginLeft) || 0;
  document.querySelector('.usp-item').style.marginLeft = (marginLeft + 100) + 'px';
});
```

```html
<button id="test-button">Test Button</button>
<div class="usp-item">USP Item</div>
```

*N.B.* To get `#test-button` you should use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), since `id` must be unique.

Comment: This works in the snippet, but doesn't seem to work on my page. Don't know why. However one of the other answers works perfectly, thanks!!